# null space of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $A\in R^{(p\times q}$, $B\in R^{q\times N}$, where $p<q$, $q>N$, $p>N$.
 Assume that $B$ is full column rank, i.e., $rank(B)=N$ and $Nullspace(A)~\cap ~Rangespace(B)=\{0\}$. Is it true to conclude that $nullspace(AB)=\{0\}$ or equivalently $Rank(AB)=N$? How can we prove this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ABv = 0$ then $Bv$ belongs to $\ker A \cap \operatorname{im} B = \{0\}$, i.e., $Bv = 0$. But $\ker B = \{ 0\}$, so we conclude that $ v= 0$. Hence we showed that $\ker AB = \{ 0\}$, i.e., $\operatorname{rank}AB = N$.

Comment: The first line is not necessarily correct. In general we can have $ABv=0$ for $v\in Ker(B)$. Therefore $ABv=0$ does not imply that Bv is in $Ker A\cap Im B$.

Comment: @sara I don't understand. Clearly $Bv$ is in the image of $B$. Also, $A(Bv) = 0$ means that $Bv$ is in the kernel of $A$.

Comment: I think I got the proof. Lets assume that $rank(AB)<N$, then there exists a non-zero $v$ such that $ABv=0$. Because $rank(B)=N$, therefore $Bv\neq 0$. Therefore $Bv$ is in Im $B$. But $Bv$ is also in $Ker A$. This means that $Bv\in Im(B)\cap Ker A$. But $Im(B)\cap Ker A=\{0\}$. Therefore, $rank(AB)=N$.

Comment: @sara Your proof is exactly my proof with unnecessary additions that obfuscate the simple ideas and where you use the word "therefore" incorrectly. It is irrelevant to invoke the fact that $Bv \neq 0$ to conclude that $Bv$ is in the image of $B$, since by definition $Bv$ is always in the image of $B$. You don't need a proof by contradiction since the direct proof works flawlessly.